# how do I get a text input using Sweet Alert

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

So, I'm using a Sweet Alert with `content: "input",` to enter a message, such as "hello world", but the resulting value is always `[object Promise]`. I have looked at other similar questions, but they have been too complicated for my limited knowledge of javascript. I have also looked at the Sweet Alert API docs, but those have been inconclusive as well.

if someone, types in "test" to the alert box, I want it to save "test" to the `message` variable.

```
swal({
    title: "Please enter a personalized greeting:",
    content: "input",
})
.then((input) => {
    let message = (input);
});
if (message != "" && message != null) {
    setCookie("greeting", message);
    swal("your personalized message is:", message, "success");
```

Comment: so, `input` in `.then(input =>` is a Promise? are you sure about that? Just tried your code, and `message` is **NOT** a promise, it's whatever you type in to the `swal` alert - your **real** code must be different

Comment: what? all I know is that it returns `[object Promise]` no matter what the input is

Comment: yes, `swal(.....).then(.....)` DOES return a promise ... but `message` WONT be a promise (which is what **you** said it was

Comment: When are you reading the `message` variable? Remember that `swal()` is running asynchronously, so you can't read the variable immediately after the call.

Comment: more code has been added

Comment: also the second alert that says [object Promise] doesn't even show up anymore

Comment: not possible, since message is NEVER set to a Promise - where is `message` initialised? - and what Barmar said is your issue - you're setting message inside the the first Promise chain, but trying to access it outside of that chain

Comment: way up above, at the beginning of the <script> tag, outside the function

Comment: how can it ever be a Promise unless you set it to a Promise ... `message = input` inside the `.then` will NOT set it before the following code runs, so you must set it to a Promise somewhere in your code, before the code you've shown

Comment: how might I do that? I don't know how to call a specific Promise outside a `.then`

Comment: Read the answer to see how you could write the code - there's a version that uses your code almost as is - also note `let message = (input);` means that `message` is not the global message you declared "way up above" ... clearly declared it as a Promise since that's what it is in the code you posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `message` before it's being set inside the Promise chain - however, the `let message = (input);` creates a `message` that is only available inside that `.then` - so the `message` variable you claim is created "way up" outside the code you posted is not even touched by the code you posted

Not sure why it's a Promise, since you never set `message` that's available to the second `swal` call to be a Promise in the code you've shown

Write your code like this and it will work

```js
swal({
    title: "Please enter a personalized greeting:",
    content: "input",
})
.then(message => {
    if (message != "" && message != null) {
        console.log("greeting", message);
        swal("your personalized message is:", message, "success");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js" integrity="sha512-AA1Bzp5Q0K1KanKKmvN/4d3IRKVlv9PYgwFPvm32nPO6QS8yH1HO7LbgB1pgiOxPtfeg5zEn2ba64MUcqJx6CA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Based on a recent comment - this is how you would use a previous promise

```js
let message;
const somePromise = swal({
    title: "Please enter a personalized greeting:",
    content: "input",
})
.then(input => message = input);


somePromise.then(() => {
    if (message != "" && message != null) {
        console.log("greeting", message);
        swal("your personalized message is:", message, "success");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js" integrity="sha512-AA1Bzp5Q0K1KanKKmvN/4d3IRKVlv9PYgwFPvm32nPO6QS8yH1HO7LbgB1pgiOxPtfeg5zEn2ba64MUcqJx6CA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```